# rsync: how to copy several subdirectories in just one calling

Tags: rsync

How to join this rules:

```
rsync -av --delete --progress ./directory/subdirectory1 /remote
rsync -av --delete --progress ./directory/subdirectory2 /remote
```

to just one line.

This does not work:

```
rsync -av --delete --progress ./directory/subdirectory1 ./directory/subdirectory2 /remote
```

because it copies the files in subdirectories `subdirectory1` and `subdirectory2` and not the subdirectories itselves.

The desired output would be:

```
ls /remote/
subdirectory1
subdirectory2
```

copying subdirectories as a whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the `--relative` (`-R`) flag to specify that source paths should be remembered in the destination. The optional `/./` part in the source path marks the point from which the path should be remembered.

```
rsync -avR --delete --progress directory/./subdirectory1 directory/./subdirectory2 /remote
```

Worked example

```
# Set up the scenario
mkdir /tmp/62569606
cd /tmp/62569606

mkdir -p src/sub1 src/sub2 dst
touch src/sub1/file1 src/sub2/file{1,2}

ls -R src

# Run the rsync command
rsync -av src/./sub1 src/./sub2 dst/
```

Here's the output

```
sending incremental file list
sub1/
sub1/file1
sub2/
sub2/file1
sub2/file2

sent 272 bytes  received 81 bytes  706.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

And the evidence (`ls -R dst`)

```
dst:
sub1  sub2

dst/sub1:
file1

dst/sub2:
file1  file2
```